# JSONParser can't request to server

Tags: java, android, json

I have a case where my **second server** I get different results when a request to the API with jsonparser. Always fail..

[Server 1](http://api.berthojoris.com/babe/statis.php) | [Server 2](http://newapi.bacaberita.com/statis.php)

On both servers (server 1 and 2) I made an example of exactly the same data, but when I make the request on the application turns on the first server to respond well, but the second server always responds with a `null`. How do I use the second server in order to run properly? I am very confused on this case..

I made ​​a simple application to perform experiments in case above :

```
package com.joris.androidjsonparsingfromurl;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView uid;
    TextView name1;
    TextView email1;
    Button Btngetdata;

    // URL to get JSON Array
    //private static String url = "http://newapi.bacaberita.com/statis.php";
    private static String url = "http://api.berthojoris.com/babe/statis.php";


    // JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_ITEM = "items";
    private static final String TAG_ISDISPLAY = "IsDisplay";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "Title";
    private static final String TAG_POST = "Post";

    JSONArray user = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Utils.setPolicyThread();

        Btngetdata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            uid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uid);
            name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            email1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result.length() > 0) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    user = result.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

                    // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                    String status = c.getString(TAG_ISDISPLAY);
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String post = c.getString(TAG_POST);

                    // Set JSON Data in TextView
                    uid.setText(status);
                    name1.setText(title);
                    email1.setText(post);

                    Log.e("HASILNYA", status+title+post);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Data Kosong Gan...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }



        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }

                            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();

            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

    }

}
```

Is there a difference cause I can not make a request to the second server? Please help.. Thanks